# how to search in active record relation using tire elastic search.(has_many,belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

i am having two tables.
here is my data schema.

```
 create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "movie_id"
    t.string   "user_comment"
    t.string   "user"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "year"
    t.text     "cast"
    t.string   "director"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "like"
    t.integer  "dislike"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.integer  "rating"
  end

end
```

I am having two models,movie & comment
models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks
    after_touch() { tire.update_index }
    mapping do
        indexes :title,boost: 100
        indexes :year,:analyzer => 'snowball'
        indexes :cast,:analyzer => 'snowball'
        indexes :user_comment
    end

    def self.search(params)
        tire.search(load: true) do |s|
            s.query {string "*#{params[:query]}*"} if params[:query].present?
            s.filter :range,year: {lte: 2004}
           end
    end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:user_comment])
  end

  def user_comment
    movie.comments.user_comment
  end
 end
```

models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie,touch: true
end
```

A search controller to search for the queries.
controller/search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if(params[:query]).present?
    @results=Movie.search(params)
    else
    @results=[]
    end
  end
end
```

views/search/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Search#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/search/index.html.erb</p>


    <%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <% if @results %>
    <% @results.each do |fetchresults| %>
    <%= fetchresults.title %> 
    <%= fetchresults.year %>
    <%= fetchresults.director %>

    <br/>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I am trying to search for the comments using tire,in movie controller.
when i am trying to run the command :- rake environment tire:import CLASS="Movie" FORCE="true"

it is showing an error:-

```
[IMPORT] Deleting index 'movies'
[IMPORT] Creating index 'movies' with mapping:
{"movie":{"properties":{"title":{"boost":100,"type":"string"},"year":{"analyzer":"snowball","type":"string"},"cast":{"analyzer":"snowball","type":"string"},"user_comment":{"type":"string"}}}}
rake aborted!    5% |||                                        | ETA:  00:00:03
undefined local variable or method `movie' for #<Movie:0x0000000337c5c8>
/home/user/Desktop/abc/elasticsearch/elastictest/app/models/movie.rb:36:in `user_comment'
/home/user/Desktop/abc/elasticsearch/elastictest/app/models/movie.rb:32:in `to_indexed_json'
Tasks: TOP => tire:import => tire:import:model
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

can anyone help me out.
my task is to search for the comments from comments table.
& one more thing how to get the movie id of that comment in my view.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is in your method

```
  def user_comment
    movie.comments.user_comment
  end
```

it should be

```
  def user_comment
    comments.user_comment
  end
```